# How do I assert object instantiation in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, tdd, instantiation, xctest

So I want to write a test to assert that an instance of a class has been created. My initial response was to write a test that checks the variable receiving the class for null but someone pointed out that this will not work in Swift because of optionals and that the program will crash if I were to unwrap something containing null.

So how do I test if a class, or any object for that matter, has been created properly?

I am using Swift 2.2 in Xcode 7.

And if downvoting, please let me know what is wrong with the question or formatting.

Comment: Yes, I meant with XCTest.

Comment: How would such a test be helpful? Or is it a stepping-stone test you will eventually delete?

Comment: @JonReid I am new to TDD so I guess from your comment that my test is overzealous :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about within the context of `XCTest`, if you want to test to make sure it was instantiated, you can do:

```
func testMyObjectInstantiation() {
    let object = MyObject(value: 42)
    XCTAssert(object != nil, "instantiation failed")
}
```

Or

```
func testMyObjectInstantiation() {
    let object = MyObject(value: 42)
    XCTAssertNotNil(object, "instantiation failed")
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I am after. New to Stackoverflow so I guess I should set this to the accepted answer somehow. Thank you for your input :-)

Answer (score 0):

if let is the Swift way to do this sort of thing:

```
if let object = MyObject.init() {
    //the object exists
} else {
    //the object is nil
}
```

Comment: You should just do `if let object = MyObject() { ... }` or `guard let object = MyObject() else { ... }`.

Comment: I could use this in combination with a variable to use in an assert, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is the guard statement

### Guard

With the guard let statement you can check a value is not nil, otherwise the else block si executed. Inside the else block you MUST stop the execution of the current code using `fatalError`, `throw` or `return`.

```
guard let num = Int(text) else {
    fatalError()
}
```

One of the beauty of the guard statement is that the next line you can use the checked variable and its type is not optional.

```
guard let num = Int(text) else {
    fatalError()
}

let next = num + 1
print(next)
```

Look at the example, the type of num is `Int`, not `Int?`. This means that if the guard does succeed I don't need to care about unwrapping.

Comment: Makes sense, but when running this in a testClass does it matter you get a fatalError? I am new to testing but as I run them now I think I run them from the "outside" of the app.